# Changing wording of the code-to-be-written and working-code off-topic reasons

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, close-reasons, close-dialog

Current wording:

> Questions **asking for code to be written** to solve a specific problem are off-topic here as there is no code to review.

However, some of these questions actually have *some* code in them already, so the wording "there is no code to review" isn't totally correct. Sometimes they are asking for **more** code to be written. But the code that they actually have in the question works, so this other close reason is **not** a better option:

> Your question must **contain working code** for us to review it here. For questions regarding specific problems encountered while coding, try Stack Overflow. After getting your code to work, you may edit this question seeking a review of your working code.

The way I see it, our "Questions asking for code to be written" is our corresponding reason to StackOverflow's

> Questions asking for code must **demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved.** Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: Stack Overflow question checklist

Which is a good reason for not including a link to Stack Overflow in the text. If we would link to Stack Overflow, it would very likely be asked there and then closed on Stack Overflow too.

However, what I think we should do is to change "Questions **asking for code to be written** to solve a specific problem are off-topic here as there is no code to review." to something that includes the possibility that there might be some code already.

What I propose is: (Changes in *italics*)

> Questions **asking for code to be written** to solve a specific problem are off-topic here as there is no code to review, *or the current code is not yet ready for a review.*"

If you have other proposal for how to change the wording, feel free to add an answer.

If you think the wording does not need to be changed at all, feel free to downvote me into oblivion.

Comment: Tangential question: http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1073/9357

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is my opinion that the first two off-topic reasons are very similar. In fact, the first reason is a 'subset' of the second:

- Questions asking for code to be written to solve a specific problem are off-topic here as there is no code to review.
- Your question must contain working code for us to review it here. For questions regarding specific problems encountered while coding, try Stack Overflow. After getting your code to work, you may edit this question seeking a review of your working code.

I agree with you that the wording is cumbersome on both of these reasons. They can be merged in to a single reason:

- Code Review is for reviewing **working** code. To be considered working there must be a description of what the code is supposed to do, and it must be clear that you are confident that the code succeeds at its intended purpose. If you are concerned that your code does not solve your problem then your question  likely belongs on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) or [Programmers SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help).

By merging off-topic reasons 1 and 2, it also frees up an option for the off-topic reason 'not your code' (nudge nudge, wink wink).

Comment: I agree with the general *spirit* of what you're saying, but not with "*there must be a description of the problem to be solved*" - it suggests that we *solve problems*, and that's SO's grounds.

Comment: What I mean is that it is very hard to review code if you don't know what the code is supposed to do.... how do I phrase that?

Comment: How about *there mus be a description of the problem **being** solved [by this code]*?

Comment: I just edited ...

Comment: I just noticed... @rolfl ding!

Comment: I'd say: "… then your question likely belongs on Stack Overflow or Programmers SE."

Comment: Agreed, and added links...

Comment: I think [some](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/11019/a-implementation) quest[ions](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/26014/linear-search-java) that would fit this close reason would fit neither on SO or on Programmers. I think your suggestion is a step in the right direction though.